# Check API response and display error message or success message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, api

I have this code

```
<div class="error">Login failed </a>

url: 'myurl',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(Login),
            contentType: "application/json",
```

**Question:** Check if API response is false display error message div if API response is true proceed it next.

Comment: code is missing! Please define your question in a proper manner!

Comment: Instead of putting parts of script better post the actual code which failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST"
                , url: url
                , data: JSON.stringify(Login)
                , contentType: "application/json",
                , success: function (resdata) {
                    if (resdata == null || resdata == '') {
                        // handle this error case
                    } else if (resdata == 'true') {
                        // handle true case
                    } else if (resdata == 'false') {
                        // handle false case
                    } 
                }
                , error: function () {
                    // handle error case
                }
            });
```

You can handle by returning "true/false" from the API response.